# Google like Autocompletion on AppEngine (latency)

Tags: jquery, google-app-engine, python-2.7, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I try to create a very fast Google like autocompletion/typeahead feature for my website. I'm calling the autocomplete with jQuery

```
$.getJSON( "/autocomplete?term=<term>")
```

and I have server side latency values of below 100ms (optimized with memcache etc.), which should be low enough for a fluent autocompletion experience like in google search. The problem is in my browser I measure latency values above 300ms on the deployed system. Where do I lose these ~200ms:

- my internet connection is fast and my google search has a latency of ~100-150ms client side
- I don't response a lot of data, just a JSON-dictionary with 4 strings (tested also with empty array and latency is about the same)
- using HTTP 1.1 (reuses TCP connections)

What else could I do (except downloading the index on page-load) to improve the speed?

**Client:**
[image]

**Server:**

[image]

**Profiler:**

[image]

Comment: Did you measure time from the moment a user types in a letter to the moment a suggestion is displayed? It may be different from the "latency" that your browser console shows.

Comment: I measured it with Chrome Network Profiler

Comment: In the Chrome Network profiler, what is the break-down between blocking, sending, waiting, and receiving? It may give you a clue where the time is spent.

Comment: Deploy a minimal version without anything except the servlet that only returns a hardcoded json. Compare times against that.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin thanks for the hint. Profiler tells me "Waiting" consumes the most of the time. So it doesn't seem that there is anything to optimize?